# Keep windows desktop in sync with sharepoint folder or UNC share

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

"Documents" folder in windows 7 is a library so you can add more than one physical folder into it, which includes network folders. For example, the documents library of my company PC includes both "c:\users\myuser\documents" and "\companyserver\myuser\documents".

This feature makes the documents folder portable and failsafe. When I log on to another domain PC in my company network, all my documents in the metwork folder are sync after some time.

The question is: Can I do the same for "desktop" folder. I tend to use a crowded desktop and it would be really nice if those files were synced to a sharepoint folder or UNC share on network so all those files are backed up. If something happens to my PC, I am safe.

Can this be achieved by windows offline folders thingy? Or do I need to use a custom software for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Microsoft SyncToy together with Task Scheduler to schedule a task which runs every weekday at noon to sync my desktop folder with a folder on the corporate file server.

If anything happens to my PC, my backups will be 1 day behind max.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to symbolically link a folder on the network share to your desktop. It would be something like:
`mklink /d c:\users\myuser\desktop \\companyserver\myuser\desktop`
That way when something is placed on your desktop, you would actually be placing it on the server. If something happens to your machine, the data is actually on the server.

I should note though, that if you log into another machine, it will not automatically pull up your desktop again. You would need to create the symbolic link on that machine as well, then it would display your desktop from the server share.

I should also note you will want to manually create the desktop folder on the server share, then copy the contents of your desktop to it, and then create the symbolic link.

Comment: I am afraid that does not do because it does not allow offline access. I need local copies for offline access.

Comment: perhaps the same solution but instead of relying on on server share, use dropbox. Dropbox cache's the files locally so it will work even without the internet, plus its not a "local" resource so it would be connected anywhere as long as you have internet access. http://www.dropbox.com (if you are going to sign up you should let me invite you - then i get more free space ;) )

Comment: life this: http://lifehacker.com/5890690/sync-your-desktop-between-computers-with-dropbox

Comment: I will try this and let you know.